# How to get the parent element too with getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have certainly extremely simple problem and I'm a little ashamed of not being able to solve it by myself.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="test">
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="test">
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML;
alert(tests);
```

**jsFiddle:**

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/td4WZ/)

Currently, the result shows me `<li>1</li>`.

This is not what I want. I want the result to be `<ul class="test"><li>1</li></ul>`.

I tried using `.parent()` (I can use jQuery) but it gives me all `<ul>` tag while I just want the first. I also know that I could use some `.split()` but it is surely not the adviced way.

I thought the problem might be coming from the `.innerHTML`, there is a function that would allow me to recover also the target element, and not just his children?

Comment: Why do you want the HTML at all? What are you going to do with the HTML? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `outerHTML`  instead of `innerHTML`

```
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].outerHTML
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/td4WZ/2/)**

You can do the same with jQuery. `$.each` to iterate over the elements and then use `this` so that it only points to that elements instead of all the elements with that class

**jQuery**

```
var $tests = $('.test');

$tests.each(function() {
    console.log(this.outerHTML)
});
```

**[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/td4WZ/4/)**

Comment: It was very basic as expected, sorry for the obvious. I will accept your answer as soon as possible.